# Centos7 iptables nor persisting after reboot

Tags: linux, iptables, centos7

I've been researching and found a lot of consistent information about how to do this.

However, it is still not working.

I set up a couple iptables rules.
I save them with: **sudo service iptables save**

I check **/etc/sysconfig/iptables** and the rules are saved there.

I then reboot the system and when it comes back, the new rules are not present.

Looking at **/etc/sysconfig/iptables**, they are still there.

I then proceed to do **sudo systemctl restart iptables** and the rules show up again.

Every time I reboot, I need to run the restart command again.

Any pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you intend to use the deprecated iptables service instead of firewalld?

Comment: I am not sure deprecated is the right word here but yes, I am using iptables service instead of firewalld.

Answer (score 2):

Did you enable the service so that it will run at startup ?

```
systemctl enable iptables
```

Comment: yes, the service is enabled and it actually loads a bunch of rules, just not the ones I've created unless I do a sudo systemctl restart iptables

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to some issue with Docker and the rancher/kubernetes deployment.

I was trying to open the ports AFTER I ran the rancher provided command lines to add k8s nodes to the cluster. That would not be an issue if the Docker problem did not show up.

When looking into the journal, I found out that the iptables rules where failing at startup stating that one of the rules that was created by Docker did not exist (although it did).

I went back to a previous snapshot, I yum updated (last time was about a month ago), I added the iptables BEFORE the kubernetes deployment, saved, rebooted and the rules where still there.

Then I continued with my installation and now everything works fine.

Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Consider switching back to firewalld. It actually plays well with Docker.

Comment: If you had mentioned you were using docker in your question then we may have been able to help.